# Why does calling a function in a different order cause a segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, stack-memory, static-memory-allocation

I am working on a program in C that processes an array of character pointers. I have several functions that operate on this array, including longest_name(), unique(), and others. When I call the longest_name() function after unique() in the main() function, the program runs fine. But when I switch the order and call longest_name() before unique(), I get a segmentation fault.

I know that the pointer char *name in the longest_name() function should be allocated by malloc to avoid the segmentation fault. However, I want to understand why the program is working in one scenario but not in the other.

My suspicion is that the issue may be related to memory allocation or pointer manipulation, but I am not sure where to start looking. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void display_name(char **stu, int indx);
void vowel_count(char **stu, int indx);
void longest_name(char **stu);
void unique(char **stu);



int main()
{
    char *name[10] = {"Aakash", "Anirudha", "Vikas", "Vinay", "Rakesh", "Thomas", "Jerry", "Alekha", "Daksh", "Peter"};
    display_name(name, 4);
    vowel_count(name,9);
    
    //longest_name(name);       //not run
    
    unique(name);
    
    longest_name(name);         //run

    return 0;
}

void unique(char **stu){
    int len = 0, found = 0;
    printf("Name whose first and last character is \'a\' :- ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        len = strlen(stu[i]);
        if(stu[i][0] == 'a' && stu[i][0] == 'a'){
            found = 1;
            printf("%s\n", stu[i]);
        }
    }
    if(found == 0){
        printf("None\n");
    }
}

void longest_name(char **stu){
    int len = 0, mx = 0;
    char *name;
    printf("\n Address is %p \n",name);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(mx < strlen(stu[i])){
            mx = strlen(stu[i]);
            strcpy(name, stu[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("Longest name is \"%s\" with length %d\n", name, mx);
}

void vowel_count(char **stu, int indx){
    
    indx--;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(i == indx){
            int len = strlen(stu[i]), cnt = 0;
            char name[len];
            strcpy(name, stu[i]);
            for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
                char c = tolower(name[j]);
                if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
                   cnt++;
            }
            printf("Number of vowels in \"%s\" are :- %d\n", name, cnt);
            break;
        }
    }
    
}

void display_name(char **stu, int indx){
    indx--;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(i == indx)
            printf("%s\n",stu[i]);
    }
}
```

I tried running the program on a different machine as I thought the issue might be related to the compiler. However, the behavior was the same on the other machine as well.

Comment: The `char* name` pointer in `longest_name` is not initialized, it points nowhere. You get "_undefined bevaviour_" (google that term).

Comment: In the `longest_name` function the variable `name` is an *unbinitialized* pointer variable. You can't use it without making it point somewhere valid.

Comment: Actually, save the *index* of the longest name, instead of copying the string. Then use it to print the string from the array.

Comment: i know that thing that it should be initialized but my question is why the same code is working in one scenario but not in other?

Comment: i want to know that why the same pointer is working when i call after the unique() and not in before unique() ?

Comment: Because it *happened to*. In one case the pointer was *accidentally* valid, in the other it was not. It's like asking why you didn't get squashed when you ran a red light. Because you didn't. You'll never get squashed if you stop at the light, but if you don't the outcome is *indeterminate*.

Comment: Because *undefined behavior*. Sometimes it can seem to work, sometimes it can give weird results, sometimes it can crash your program, and sometimes it can set fire to your cat. Well, maybe not the last, but it's generally unpredictable. Many think that when it seems to work it's actually because of bad luck. Use memory debuggers like Valgrind and compiler sanitizers, to catch these kind of problems.

Comment: I'm not trying to make the program run, and I already know where to correct the issue to make it run fine. Instead, I'm curious about why this issue is occurring. Specifically, I want to know why the program runs without issues when I call longest_name() after unique() in the main() function, but I get a segmentation fault when I switch the order and call unique() after longest_name(). The code is the same in both scenarios, but changing the order of function calls is causing the problem.

Comment: @AmanPachouri the issue occurs because the pointer was not initialized. It contains un undetermined value. Depending on what your program was doing before, it may happen that this undetermined value accidentally points to a valid memory location and no segfault occurs. The outcome is undetermined. Like if you run a red light, sometimes you'll get overrun by a truck, sometimes you get hit by a bicycle, and sometimes you get way with it. You don't know what is going to happen.

Comment: Side note: Have a close eye on `const` correctness! All functions *not* modifying the C-strings should accept pointers to `const`, e.g. `void unique(char const** stu);` – especially: Albeit string literals ("a literal!") actually have type `char[]` (a legacy resulting from times where `const` did not yet exist) they are still *immutable*. So you never should assign them to anything else than `const` pointers, otherwise you *will* some day run into trying to modify them (undefined behaviour!), so in your case: `char* name[] = { ... };`

Comment: If the program is running successfully by luck in one case then why it is so consistent like on every attempt it is running successfully, it should fail sometime and  why is failing consistently in the other case  on every attempt.

Comment: Side note: If there are exactly ten names anyway I'd rather let deduce array size from the initialiser – see size having been left out in my previous comment.

Comment: The consistency is because the value remaining in the uninitialised variable (from the previous use of that memory) is consistent in each case. *Undefined behaviour* does not mean *random*.

Comment: @Aconcagua It "should" not do anything. It's free to do whatever it wants.

Comment: A bit more explicit about why the programme *accidentally* works in one case (general explanation): Function parameters and local variables (which parameters actually are nothing else than) are typically stored on the stack (sometimes in registers) – calling a function reserves and fills a part of that stack, returning from frees it again – while leaving the contents there unchanged. On calling another function the uninitialised variable might (by accident) be placed exactly at the location a correctly initialised variable held in previous function call – and the new call then uses this value.

Comment: Error in my previous comment (sorry!): Should, of course, be: `char const* name[] = { ... };`

Comment: @klutt What are you exactly referring to by 'it should' – or do you mean by *'it'* the question author? In the latter case: Indeed, actually is free – my comment is just an advice, but a strong one. I'd put a hand in the fire for if not following it some day *'it'* will run into UB for modifying literals ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua I'm referring to the program. OP is having expectations on how UB should manifest itself.

Comment: @klutt I think you intended to refer to someone else, my only comments before referred to that the pointers should point to `const` apart from those intended for modification...

Comment: @Aconcagua I see what I did wrong. I typed @, then a, then pressed tab enter :)

Comment: Off-topic: `stu[i][0] == 'a' && stu[i][0] == 'a'` – this looks pretty much as if you intended something else, or why would you want to check the same condition twice?

Comment: @klutt Never mind ;)

Comment: @AmanPachouri *'how to fix it?'* – you actually already provided the answer yourself: let `name` point to a valid memory location – `malloc`ing memory is *one* way, but as you don't re-allocate anyway a locally defined array (`char name[128]`) might be preferrable.

Comment: sorry, it should be stu[i][0] == 'a' && stu[i][len-1] == 'a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your variable `name` in your `longest_name` function is uninitialised.

You have declared it like this:

```c
char *name;
```

and have not made it point anywhere.

Many compilers will manually initialise the pointer to zero, such as having written:

```c
char *name = NULL;
```

... but this is not guaranteed, so it is good practice to always initialise your pointers to `NULL` if you do not wish to make them point anywhere yet. Nonetheless, it is important to note that initialising to `NULL` just means the pointer **definitely** does not point anywhere.

In your case, it looks like your `name` pointer might have been initialised to some random value - such as whetever was at that location on the stack previously. If the latter is the case, it would explain why your program works sometimes, and at other times it does not. As mentioned by a comment, the order with which you call the functions will determine what is on the stack (beneath the stack pointer) by the time the second function is called. Thus, it is perfectly plausible that when you call your `unique` function first and THEN your `longest_name` function, by sheer luck your `name` variable in your `longest_name` function is initialised to some "valid" memory location, which means you are able to write data to it.

What is happening is described as *undefined behaviour*. Essentially, this means that your program can sometimes perform as you expected, and sometimes do something completely different. *Undefined behaviour* happens when something in the program has not been written correctly, but that does not necessarily always make the program crash instantly. However, if you write a program correctly, you can avoid UB (*undefined behaviour*) completely.

Thus, you should never do something like:

```c
char *whatever = "It was a sunny day.";
char *str;
strcpy(str, whatever);
```

... because you have not made the pointer `str` point anywhere valid, and you cannot copy data to a memory location that does not exist or one that cannot be accessed by your program.

In your case, your `longest_name` function should allocate memory and make the `name` pointer **point to** this allocated memory, before copying anything to it, such as:

```c
name = malloc((strlen(stu[i]) + 1)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(name, stu[i]);
```

... remembering to `free` the memory after using it.

Remember, a string stored as a `char*` always needs to include an extra byte for the null terminator character `'\0'` or simply `0` in ASCII. This is where you have gone wrong in your `vowel_count` function, your declaration of name should be:

```c
char name[len + 1];
```

Note also that by declaring `name` like that you are declaring a variable-length array (VLA), which can be tricky. If you need memory with a dynamic size (determined at runtime) it is usually better to use dynamic memory allocation (using `malloc`, and `free` for deallocation).

Furthermore, in your `longest_name` function, you don't need to allocate any extra memory, all you need is to make your `name` pointer point to the longest string, and print that out, such as:

```c
void longest_name(char **stu){
    size_t len = 0, mx = 0; // strlen returns a number of type size_t
    char *name = NULL; // initialise to NULL since not pointing anywhere
    printf("\n Address is %p\n", name); // this will either be zero or undefined
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ // use unsigned as you start from zero
        if(mx < (len = strlen(stu[i]))){ // assign len to only call strlen once
            mx = len;
            name = stu[i]; // simply make name point to the longest string
        }
    }
    printf("Longest name is \"%s\" with length %zu\n", name, mx);
}
```

In conclusion, your program runs sometimes and at other times it crashes, becuase your `name` variable sometimes ends up pointing somewhere "valid", and sometimes it doesn't. You can fix this by always ensuring your pointers point somewhere valid before using them.

Comment: Rather than using `malloc` and `strcpy`, you could use [`strdup`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) instead - that's what it was made for.

Comment: Indeed, but I wanted to make the point as well that, in this case, there wasn't even any need for dynamic memory! Great point, though

Comment: Yeah, sorry - didn't read all the way to the end of the answer.  You still should have initialized `name` though, either to NULL or to `stu[0]`.

Comment: Whoops, am contradicting myself there as well! I'll edit now :) thanks